# How do I match any number after comma using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this expression capture all numbers.

```
var regex = /\,([-+]?(\d*[.])?\d*)/g;
```

But it still captures preceding comma.

How do I get rid of it?

> http://regexr.com/3e47t

Capture variable and detect comment in groups

> http://regexr.com/3eq7d

Validate start letters and valid characters for code validate

> http://regexr.com/3eq7g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it still captures preceding comma.

No, it *matches* the preceding comma, but it doesn't *capture* it:

```js
var regex = /\,([-+]?(\d*[.])?\d*)/g;
var str = "testing,123";
var match = regex.exec(str);
console.log("The match was      : " + match[0]); // ",123"
console.log("But the capture was: " + match[1]); // "123"
```